# In java, does it matter to return the value within the synchroized block?

Tags: java, synchronized

The code is like below

```
public class UAUtil {
private static String sUA = null;
private static Object sLock = new Object();
public static void clear() {
    synchronized (sLock) {
        sUA = null;
    }
}
public static String getUserAgent() {
    synchronized (sLock) {
        if (sUA == null) {
            Context context = CoreService.getAppContext();
            sUA = ...;
        }
    }

    return sUA;
}
```

So I wonder does it matter to return the sUA within or out of the synchronized block?

Comment: there is so much wrong with this, there is not really enough space to address it all on SO. **Concurrency is easy, Concurrency correctly is extremely hard.** This is actually *to broad* as well as the partial duplicate, and is not complete code so *no MCVE* applies as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### No one can tell you a correct answer because the code looks to be incomplete.

That said, given the code you did post why is `sUA` an instance variable?

Why even keep that as state. A better thing to do if you do not need that state is to `return <whatever code is setting sUA>`.

If there is code that you do not show that uses that state then pleas show it and ...

Also `private static Object sLock = new Object();` is not a proper way to use an object reference to `syncrhonize` on. It must be declared `final` to properly guarantee semantics.

A better way would be to make `sUA` the lock. Instead of using `null` use the `NullObjectPattern` and have a value that represents whatever you are using `null` to mean.

Using a `private static final AtomicReference` with a value such as `""` or some other *null* value to represent *not set*, you could use have something to `synchronize` on and hold the value at the same time. Making for more **correct** and **cleaner** code that will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score -3):

> So I wonder does it matter to return the sUA within or out of the
>   synchronized block?

no it does not matter at all, if you `return` outside of the `synchronized` block it will be absolutely fine and also if its within the `synchronized` block the `lock` will be released correctly so there is no harm.

Here is a good [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971946/in-java-return-value-within-synchronized-block-seems-like-bad-style-does-it-re) to jon skeet's & Mark Byers answers to a similar question.

Comment: @downvoter any thoughts on improving my answer?

Comment: this is only partially *correct* given that `sUA` leaks outside the method block and is *"public"* state that is non `final`. It can change before the `return` depending on what `...;` contains.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson thanks for the thought. Appreciated.